# Sub Menu Disappears On Hover? STICKY / FIXED NAVIGATION

Tags: html, css

I have researched so many solutions to this problem but have yet to find one that works for mine. I have a sticky / fixed navigation.

When the navigation is at the top, the submenu doesn't work. However, once you begin scrolling, if you then go back to the navigation, the submenu then works. But if you scroll back up to the top, it stops working.

First and foremost, Thanks so much for all your guys help. I really appreciate anyone that takes time to answer this question or any of my other questions.

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     // Llamado cuando se cargue la página
  posicionarMenu();

  $(window).scroll(function() {    
      posicionarMenu();
  });

  function posicionarMenu() {
      //var altura_del_header = $('header').outerHeight(true);
   var altura_del_header = $('header').outerHeight(true);
      var altura_del_menu = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true);
      var altura_adminbar = $('#wpadminbar').outerHeight(true);

      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= altura_del_header-altura_del_menu){
          $('.navbar').addClass('fixed');
          $('.navbar').css('top',(altura_adminbar)+'px');
          $('.content').css('margin-top', (altura_del_menu-altura_adminbar) + 'px');
      } else {
          $('.navbar').removeClass('fixed');
          $('.content').css('margin-top', '0');
      }
  }
    </script>
```

```css
/**
 * 4.2 Navigation
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

.main-navigation {
 clear: both;
 min-height: 45px;
 position: relative;
 width: 950px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.nav-menu,
div.nav-menu > ul {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 background-color: none;
 font-weight: 500;
 position: relative;
 float: left; 
}

.nav-menu li {
 display:inline-block !important;
 position: relative;
}

.nav-menu li a {
 color: #fff;
        font-weight:900;
 display:block;
 font-family: 'raleway';
        font-size: 14px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 padding: 18px 50px 18px 0px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;
        line-height: 1;
 opacity: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
        -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
         transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

.nav-menu li:hover > a,
.nav-menu li a:hover {
 color: #f286c3; 
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

}

.nav-menu .sub-menu,
.nav-menu .children {
 background-color: transparent;
        display:none;
 border-top: 0;
 position: absolute;
 z-index:999999999;
        font-weight:600; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height:1;
}

.nav-menu .sub-menu,
.nav-menu .children 
{

}



.nav-menu .sub-menu ul,
.nav-menu .children ul {
 border-left: 0;
 left: 100%;
 top: 0px;
}

ul.nav-menu ul a,
.nav-menu ul ul a {
        background-color: #000;
 color: #feeef9;
 margin: 0 auto;
        font-size:12px;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:600; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 15px 15px;
}

ul.nav-menu ul a:hover,
.nav-menu ul ul a:hover {
 background-color: #777777;
 color: #feeef9;
        font-weight:600; 
}

ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul,
.nav-menu ul li:hover > ul {
   display: block;
}

.nav-menu .current_page_item > a,
.nav-menu .current_page_ancestor > a,
.nav-menu .current-menu-item > a,
.nav-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a {
 color: #fff;
}

.menu-toggle {
 display: none;
}

.social-icons-widget{
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 text-align: left;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:-10px;
}

aside#simple-social-icons-2{
 padding: 7px 0px 0px 0px;
}

/* Navbar */
.navbar {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 border-bottom: 2px dotted #c3c0ab;
        opacity:0.95;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
     <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h3>
     <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></a>
     <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
     
    <div class="social-icons-widget">
     <div id="social-widget"><?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'social-footer' ) ) : dynamic_sidebar( 'social-footer' ); endif; ?></div>
    
    
    </div><!-- .widget-area -->
    
    
    <div class="searchbar">
     
     <div class="container">
         <form class="searchbox">
             <input type="search" placeholder="Search......" name="s" class="searchbox-input" onkeyup="buttonUp();" required>
             <input type="submit" class="searchbox-submit" value="">
             <span class="searchbox-icon"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/searchbar.png"></span>
         </form>
     </div>
    </div>
     
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    
    
   
  </div><!-- #navbar -->
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: Confused by what you're asking. I put up the current css code that I am using. Wondering if anyone can take a look to see why it's not working?

Comment: Can you include `html` used at Question ?, create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ to demonstrate ?

Comment: I don't think @guest271314 meant can we have your css _as html_, I think he meant _can we have the html that the CSS is layout-ing?_ (**after your update**: Now there just the CSS again. We cannot _see_ what your problem is without a combination of CSS **and** HTML, and we can't help you otherwise.)

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to figure out a way to replicate the issue using stack snippets and it took me awhile. I am not sure how I will get this to accurately replicate the problem being that the actual navigation is PHP. Nonetheless, I have provided the snippet, and a link to the website where the problem is persisting. Please let me know if there is anything else I need to add / do. Thanks!

Comment: please include only the HTML / CSS relevant to the issue, it will be easier to find out what's wrong in a smaller block of code. Also: better if you include the HTML generated by your PHP code instead of the PHP itself, since your problem is not related to the PHP part.

Answer (score 2):

So first thank you to everyone that commented.

I discovered the solution to my problem after doing quite a bit of trial and error. Wanted to post the solution to anyone who may have an issue with their Fixed / Sticky Navigation + Wordpress.

In brief, I had to make changes to the navbar, not the sub-menu or nav-menu. My main content was covering the sub-menu drop down.

I ended up adding the following to my CSS

```
      position: absolute;
      top:0px;
      z-index: 9999999;
```

So now with the amendments to the navbar. It looks like:

```
.navbar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #c3c0ab;
        opacity:0.95;
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        z-index: 9999999;
}
```